# Table not update with new data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

rIdThere are two text boxes in page. One is for UserId and the other one is for email. Both are retrieved data from table aspnet_membership and are set 'read-only'.
For email text box, it will change read-only = false. Then user get to enter a new email then hit button save. It should update the email in table with the new email but unfortunately no changes made. Can some one tell me what should I remove/add to make it works. Here is my code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string email = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email;
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    string UserId = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

    TextBox2.Text = email;
    TextBox3.Text = UserId;
}
```

---

```
 protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

---

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_membership SET Email = @email WHERE UserName = @id1", conn);

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id1", TextBox3.Text);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have refatored your code, now it should work

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
SqlConnection conn = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_membership SET Email = @email WHERE UserName = @id1", conn);

cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id1", TextBox3.Text);   
 try { 
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   }
  catch(Exception ex){ 
  throw ex;    
  }
finally{    
conn.Close();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thnks. But When I apply your code,it says that must declare the scalar var @model.

Comment: @ClarifySeeker I was calling the executeNonQuery before assinging the parameters to the query, I have edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you forgot to open connection

```
con.Open();
```

run command

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and then close connection

```
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is showing no signs of committing any data back to its Data Source.

You need a Data Adapter, and you need to set its Insert Command to the command above.

```
SQLDataAdapter adapt = new SQLataAdapter();
```

you then need to open a connection :-

```
conn.open();

adapt.UpdateCommand = cmd;

adapt.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.close();
```

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try directly updating the user via Membership class in your button click event:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var memUser = Membership.GetUser(TextBox3.Text) //Fetch the user by user Id
     memUser.Email = TextBox2.Text // Assign the new email address
     Membership.UpdateUser(memUser) // update the user record.
}
```